# Extract CAD from Windchill PLM

Tags: cad, ptc-windchill

I am trying to retrieve the CAD model of a part in order to store it in an external application.

I started doing that with info*engine. With info*engine i can retrieve the history of a part, or link two parts together but i didn't find a way to extract the part from windchill.

Any one have an idea how to proceed? Is the use of info*engine the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by Windchill specific API in your java code. Info*engine not needed.

```
QueryResult qresult = PersistenceHelper.manager.navigate(prt, EPMBuildRule.ROLE_AOBJECT_ROLE, EPMBuildRule.class, true);
```

Here `prt`is your wtpart which have cad data in it.

Comment: Is it correct to use EPMBuildRuleAssociationLink for non-latest WTParts? This seems to work but i'm not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

There is also a helper class with a static method that might help you:

```
EPMDocument[] epmDocs = ObjectDependencyUtility.getAssociated(part);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vignesh Vino said, I would try to do this with the standard API.
Use the following method:

```
private QueryResult getActivelyAssociatedParts(EPMDocument doc) throws
  WTException
{
QueryResult qr = null;
if (VersionControlHelper.isLatestIteration(doc))
{
  qr = PersistenceHelper.manager.navigate(doc,
                                          EPMBuildRule.BUILD_TARGET_ROLE,
                                          EPMBuildRule.class);
}
else
{
  qr = PersistenceHelper.manager.navigate(doc,
                                          BuildHistory.BUILT_ROLE,
                                          BuildHistory.class);
}
return qr;
}
```